# How can I prove XOR true true = false in lambda calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus

I know that XOR= (a)((b)(false)(true))(b)
but how can I reduce  [xor true true ]and get the false result from this expression?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the λ in front of your definition of XOR. Also, you have to define `true` and `false` as standard Church booleans:

```
true = λab.a
false = λab.b
XOR = λab.a(b false true)b
```

Then

```
    XOR true true
--> (λab.a(b false true)b) true true
--> true (true false true) true
--> true false true
--> false
```